# android live wallpaper crash at Configure Wallpaper

Tags: android

I am developing a live wallpaper for android. i have pretty much follow android's cube live wallpaper example, but i am getting crashes when Configuring the live wallpaper

to clarify, it doesn't crash when i

1. go to Live Wallpaper selection screen
2. select my wallpaper
3. hit settings from there

but it does crash when i

1. have already set my wall paper as the live wallpaper
2. long press the screen to bring up Wallpaper (see first image)
3. hit Configure... (see second image)

appreciate any help.

[image]
[image]

EDIT: BTW, nothing from logcat.

Answer (score 1):

never mind. figured out what i did wrong.
added android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" to Application tag instead of Service tag like i should have.